# For a contract, I landed an asteroid on Kerbin, but it doesn't think the vessel landed. Is this fixable? (Pic attached)

Tags: kerbal-space-program

In Kerbal Space Program career mode, I was completing a contract with the following statement:

```
Bring a newly discovered Class A asteroid to Kerbin and land it.
```

Conditions:

```
-Have a newly discovered Class A asteroid in tow
-Land your vessel on Kerbin
-Maintain stability for ten seconds
```

After completing the daunting task of recovery and reenty, I safely landed my vessel with the asteroid attached, velocity and altitude at 0, on the water. However, while the first and third requirements are checked off, the second one is not showing to be completed.

Screenshot:

[image]

Is there something I missed or is there any way I could fix it? I'm not opposed to using some cheat to get it done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It is **Splashed**, not **Landed**. **Landed** requires to land on... land.

Aside of using debug toolbar (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>) to "cheat" there are several options available to bring it ashore. However, depending on your distance from shore it might be faster to bring new one back home.

1. Jet powered Boat with Claw.
2. Seaplane, with Claw.
3. VTOL, with claw.
4. Gargantuan cargo ship with crane.

Hint: If you have access to ISRU, you can create rocket fuel from asteroid for extra speed in transport craft. It will also lower asteroid mass.

You can also use mods to make it easier:

- [Trajectories](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/94368-112-trajectories-v162-2016-05-18-atmospheric-predictions/) will allow you to predict landing spot after planet rotation and aerobraking
- [Firespitter](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/22583-firespitter-propeller-plane-and-helicopter-parts-v71-may-5th-for-ksp-10/) and similar mods - wider selection of airplane parts will make it easier.
- [KAS](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/83468-112-kerbal-attachment-system-kas-058/)/[KIS](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/101928-112-kerbal-inventory-system-kis-1212/) - winches, lines, on-site part attachment. And C4 explosives.
- [HyperEdit](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/34785-113-hyperedit-v1521-june-22-2016-cheat-teleporter-orbitplanet-editor-more/) - its a cheat engine for KSP. You can use it to teleport rock to ground.
- [MechJeb](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/111978-113-anatid-robotics-mumech-mechjeb-autopilot-258-22-jun-2016/)/[PilotAssistant](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/90252-11x-pilot-assistant-atmospheric-piloting-aids-1125-apr-21/) - autopilot is rather useful for long missions (MJ for space, PA for atmospheric travel)
- [KER](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/17833-111-kerbal-engineer-redux-1110-2016-04-29/) - knowledge is power, KER gives you it.

As for internal game mechanics, here is summary for curious people:
Crafts (which includes Kerbals on EVA, debris, and flags) have states (Landed, Splashed etc...). Contracts system is simple set of rules, and it simply checks craft state. Craft state can be edited in save file (backups recommended).

Comment: `It is Splashed, not Landed` - wow, that is *harsh*...!  : (

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to cheat it not long after. If you access the debug toolbar, go to the "Contracts" section, and go to the "Active" subsection, you will find all of your active missions.

On the right of each mission is a "Can" button, meaning "Cancel" (not always available), and a "Com" button, meaning "Complete". Just hit the Com button to force-complete the mission.

Please use sparingly.